# Combine one image to form a tile of the same image without duplication in ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, images

I'm trying to create a tile of the same image with ffmpeg.

If I had 25 png images I could display them on a 5x5 grid with this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" -filter_complex tile=5x5 output.png
```

However, this depends on there already being 25 images already in the directory. How can you use the same image 25 times without creating duplicate copies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ffmpeg, a single image is a video of 1 frame with a default framerate of 25. You can "create" 25 images by looping it till a 1 second stream is generated.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 1 -i single.png -filter_complex tile=5x5 output.png
```